# Can't get stats while using sout with libvlc

Tags: vlc, libvlc

I want to display a stream, and monitor the video stats of the displayed stream while recording it using libvlc.  When I use sout + duplicate to record the stream while displaying it, I can only get the `demux_bitrate` stat from the displayed stream using `libvlc_media_get_stats` function.  I am looking to get `decoded_video`, `displayed_pictures`, etc as well.

I've tried using the duplicate module to try to make this happen but I can't seem to make this work - am not sure if what I want to do is supported.  Code below is tweaked from https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/display/ example for transcoding a stream while displaying the original version.

```
:sout=#duplicate{dst='transcode{vcodec=h264}:std{access=file,mux=ts,dst=c:\junk\test.mp4}',dst=display}
```

The stream displays, the file is generated, but the only valid stat is `demux_bitrate` which seems like the stat that would be accessible from the non-display stream instead of the displayed version.

Answer (score 0):

Display and save with Transcoding

```
:sout=#duplicate{dst=display,dst="transcode{vcodec=h264}:standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=c:\junk\test.mp4}"}
```

Display and save without Transcoding

```
:sout=#duplicate{dst=display,dst=standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=c:\junk\test.mp4}}
```

Comment: I finally had a chance to (re)try this solution and it gives me the same result as above in my description - I am able to stream to file and display that stream but the only stat I see is the demux_bitrate.  I was hoping to get other stats like decoded, displayed, etc to show up.  My workaround to this issue was to open to separate camera streams, one for displaying the stream and getting the stats related to decode/display and the other stream for saving the data to disk.  I feel like this is a bad compromise but I'm living with it for the moment as the other stats are very useful to me.